# Differences between wc and grep

Tags: git

I would like to know what is the difference between the 2 command below for retrieving the number of commits from line 50 to 60:

```
git log -L 50,60:filename.txt | grep -c ^commit
```

and

```
git log -L 50,60:filename.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

[`grep -c ^commit`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-c+%5Ecommit) outputs the number of lines that start with *commit* - in your case, this means the number of commits.

[`wc -l`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wc+-l) prints the number of lines in the output of the piped command. In your case this will print the total number of lines output by the `git log` command which is probably much larger than the number of commits and also a pretty useless value.

Answer (score 1):

`git log -L 50,60:filename.txt` outputs a lot of things. `wc -l` counts how many lines the output has. `grep -c ^commit` finds all the lines that start with the string `commit` and outputs the number of these lines. You could remove `-c` and have a try.